# Issue with creating Facebook events through Graph API. I get an ID, but it's not created

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

So, I'm using the Graph API with the Javascript SDK to create an event. It works fine and I get the ID like I'm supposed to from a successful event creation. However, when I go to look at the event or find it in the graph explorer, it's like it hasn't been created.

Here's my code:

```
function createEvent(name, start, end, location) {
start = Date.UTC(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth(), start.getDate(), start.getHours());
end = Date.UTC(end.getFullYear(), end.getMonth(), end.getDate(), end.getHours());

FB.api('me/events', 'post', { name: name, start_time: start, end_time: end, location: location }, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
}
```

I have no idea what's wrong with it and why the event would appear to not have been created.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if the start_time is not formatted to ISO time format, FB will give you back and EventID but not create the Event.. Try to use the Graph API explorer to do a Post, add parameters name and start_time then grab and time formatted string from another Graph API result, it should work

-John Gentilin